# Visual Studio 2017 vs Visual Studio 2019 difference with android app development

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to make a simple android app by following this tutorial right here: https://youtu.be/5CgQUbnf1Qk

In this video, the guy just seems to drag a button onto his app, and doesnt need to do any realignment for it to be where he wants it to be. He is using VS 2017, and i am using VS 2019, now the problem is when i tried to follow his example, my button goes over the text bar, and i have not found a way to get the button to go under the text bar like in the video. Does anyone know how i can fix this, please? Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO ! You can show the code of `main_activity.xml` here , I will check that . The dragging ways also generate the xml code , you also can modify `xml` code to change the interface of View .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks for your answer, i will comment back later with the code, im focussing more on C# than xml for the moment, so i dont really know how all of that works yet. Is it correct that in VS 2019 you can not drag buttons freely anymore? If that is still an option, could you please tell me where i could find it? Thanks again and i will definitely respond back with the code.

Comment: Hi , it depends on which layout used in xml . You can have a look at my shared answer .

Comment: You can refer [using android Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/designer-walkthrough?tabs=windows) to more about designer , and better show code of xml here .Then will check where problem is .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at **[Xamarin.Android Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/)** , there is a **LinearLayout** you can have a try . If you set `android:orientation="vertical"` and drag `Button` below `TextView` , then it will show as your wants .

The `Xml` code will look like follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The effect of user-interface :

[image]

Aout **[using the Xamarin.Android Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/designer-walkthrough?tabs=windows)** , you can have a look at this doc .

Comment: Thank you very much, this definitely solved my problem. Thanks for also including more educational material for me to learn from. This will definitely come in handy.

Comment: @VenomSnake03 Glad be helpful , remember to mark the answer when you have time .Then other people will know how to solve it  :-)